# Flutter and getx: update() does not notify GetBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a very strange issue for my current project using Flutter and `getx` package. Short: the Notifier is not working. On `initState` from a `GetBuilder` I try to update an variable (.obs) and call `update()`, but the view knows nothing about it.

**Reproduction code**

GetxController:

```dart
class HoursController extends GetxController {
  final AwController awController = AwController();
  final hours = [].obs;

  void loadHours({required Kunde kunde}) async {
    this.hours.assignAll(["Test1", "Test2"]);
    update(["hours"]);
  }
}
```

View:

```
GetBuilder<HoursController>(
  id: "hours",
  initState: (_) {
    HoursController().loadHours(kunde: this.kunde);
  },
  builder: (controller) {
    if (controller.hours.length == 0) {
      return Container(
        child: Text("Nothing"),
      );
    }
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: controller.hours.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(controller.hours[index]),
          );
        });
  },
)
```

**Expected behavior**
After calling the function on `initState`, which changes the `hours` variable, I expect that the `update["hours"]` will notify the view to refresh the state. But nothing happens. The console shows the correct data. So the variable really was refreshed, but the view was not notified about it.

**Flutter Version:**
Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (8 weeks ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
Engine • revision 241c87ad80
Tools • Dart 2.13.4

**Getx Version:**
4.3.8

**By the way**
I'm working with Flutter Desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved... the issue was the HoursController().loadHours(kunde: this.kunde);. Here I create a new instance of HoursController. But I need to use the instance created above with Get.find().

Answer (score 0):

if your `GetBuilder` is not updating with `update()` method then also check if you're overriding `refresh` method of your controller without calling `super.refresh()` in the overridden method. I had the same problem took me awhile to realise.